# Creating a boolean form widget that accepts null value

Tags: symfony1, widget, symfony-1.4, propel, symfony-forms

My Symfony model has a field which is boolean but also accepts NULL so effectively is a tri-state value.

How can I write a widget for this? Symfony auto-generates a sfWidgetFormCheckbox but that
can not be set to NULL.

I tried a sfWidgetFormChoice with but I had to specify the values as strings to get them work:

```
$this->setWidget('wt', new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
    'choices' => array(true => 'true', false => 'false', null => 'null')
)));
```

It works for storing values but whenever I save a "false" value, the select jumps back to 'null'. I tried several combinations of 'false', '0', '' etc. but got nothing to work in all three cases.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `'null' => 'null'` and creating a custom validator that looks for the string `null` and returns the proper value?

Answer (score 4):

An example right from the [docs](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/05-Custom-Widgets-and-Validators#chapter_05_building_a_simple_widget_and_validator):

```
class sfWidgetFormTrilean extends sfWidgetForm
{
  public function configure($options = array(), $attributes = array())
  {

    $this->addOption('choices', array(
      0 => 'No',
      1 => 'Yes',
      'null' => 'Null'
    ));
  }

  public function render($name, $value = null, $attributes = array(), $errors = array())
  {
    $value = $value === null ? 'null' : $value;

    $options = array();
    foreach ($this->getOption('choices') as $key => $option)
    {
      $attributes = array('value' => self::escapeOnce($key));
      if ($key == $value)
      {
        $attributes['selected'] = 'selected';
      }

      $options[] = $this->renderContentTag(
        'option',
        self::escapeOnce($option),
        $attributes
      );
    }

    return $this->renderContentTag(
      'select',
      "\n".implode("\n", $options)."\n",
      array_merge(array('name' => $name), $attributes
    ));
  }
}
```